# Drawer layout and OnItemClickListener conflict - Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, drawerlayout

When I change the order of `ListView` and `Drawer layout` (having navigation Menu) in layout Xml. 
Case 1: If `ListView` is at Top: Then it get overplayed with navigation Menu.
Case 2: If Drawer layout is at Top: Then `onItemClickListner` does not work.

**Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ShopkeeperMainActivity"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"></ListView>


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="false"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="?android:attr/windowSwipeToDismiss"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:fadingEdge="none|horizontal|vertical"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">


        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_menu_header"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu_shopkeper"></android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tried these in different ways. But none of it worked:

```
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

In **Case 1** I tried this:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(drawer_btn_count_flag==100)
            drawer_btn_count_flag = 2; // reset back 2 

        if(drawer_btn_count_flag%2==0) {
             listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            drawer_btn_count_flag++;
        }
        else {
            listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // back vivisble
            drawer_btn_count_flag++;
        }
```

But it makes `listview` items visible before the navigation menu hides. Which looks awkward.

Comment: Use Like this. <DrawerLayout>... <CoordinatorLayout>..<ListView/> ..</CoordinatorLayout>... <NavigationView/> </DrawerLayout>

Comment: It worked +1. Any explanation of that would be appreciated.